# Benefits and drawbacks of using Hive Warehouse Connector over Hadoop File Location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Normally we are using the Hadoop file location of the hive table to access data from our spark ETLs. Are there any benefits of using Hive Warehouse Connector instead of our current approach? And is there any drawback of using the Hive Warehouse connector for ETLs?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a drawback.

Hive stores the schema and provides faster predicate push downs. If you read from the filesystem, you will need to often define the scheme on your own